# Get List from .net Web Service on Android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-spinner, android-ksoap2

I have .net Web Service and I want to use it on android. This web service's methods return List(Of String) and I didn't get response on android. What can I do ? Here is the code..

I'm working on it for 3 days and I didn't find any solution yet.

In short, I need some list from .net web service and add this list's items to spinner. Please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner myspinner;
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Sektorler";  
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";  
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Sektorler";
    private static final String URL = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/webservice1.asmx";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_main , SektorDoldur());
        myspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private ArrayList<String> SektorDoldur() {

        ArrayList<String> sektorler = new ArrayList<String>();

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;     
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {

       androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
       SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

       if (response.hasProperty("String")) {

       if (response.getPropertyAsString("String") == null) {
    //do something
       } else {

           for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){
//             sektorler.add(i, response.getPropertyAsString("String"));
               sektorler.add(response.getPropertyAsString(i));
           }
        }

}

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return sektorler;

    }
```

**Also I'm trying this code but it doesn't work.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner myspinner;
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Sektorler";  
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";  
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Sektorler";
    private static final String URL = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/webservice1.asmx";
    private String[] denemeList;

    private String[] SektorDoldur(){
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;     
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {

       androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
       SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
       denemeList = new String[response.getPropertyCount()];

       for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){ 
           denemeList[i] = response.getPropertyAsString(i).toString();
       }      
} 
        catch (Exception e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return denemeList;      
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SektorDoldur();

        myspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_main , denemeList);
        myspinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: Does your SektorDoldur() method is returning any data?

Comment: my web service is working good. Therefore SektorDoldur() method has to returning data if this codes is true.

Comment: Heve you mention permission in manifest file for using internet (i.e android.permission.INTERNET).And have a look at this post http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-web-service-access-tutorial.html

Comment: actually, SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); Line gives me error but I know NAMESPACE and METHOD_NAME are true.

yes my manifest file has internet permission.

Comment: I got it !! I find a solution and I can't answer own questions.

Comment: Good to here you can post your answer after certain amount of time. :)

Comment: Thanks for your attention :) I will post my solution. It may be useful for someone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I got it !!**

**this is false;**

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

**Lets see this code, it's true;**

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

**Finally there are some trick about it.**

1. First of all delete ksoap2 jar file from your project.
2. Save it and close Eclipse.
3. Then copy ksoap2 jar file, go to your workspace folder.
4. Open your project folder, click "libs" folder and paste it.
5. Open again Eclipse and Run Project!!

   ```
       private Spinner myspinner;
       private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Sektorler";  
       private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";   
       private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Sektorler";
       private static final String URL = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/webservice1.asmx";
       private String[] denemeList;

       private void SektorDoldur(){

           SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
           SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
           envelope.dotNet = true;     
           envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
           HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
           androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

           try {

          androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
          SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
          denemeList = new String[response.getPropertyCount()];

         for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){ 

              denemeList[i] = response.getPropertyAsString(i).toString();

         }      
   } 
           catch (Exception e) {           
               e.printStackTrace();
           }       
       }


       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           SektorDoldur();

           myspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, denemeList);
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
           myspinner.setAdapter(adapter);

       }
   ```