# How to create web service with C# and parse SOAP message on Android?

Tags: c#, android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

Although Ksoap2 is a good library to handle SOAP messages in Android application development, it is not well documented. I've read a lot of blog posts and Q&As but information is often incomplete. Is it possible to provide a complete example of:

1. How to create simple web service using C#?
2. How to consume a webmethod on this web service on Android and parse the returned SOAP message to generate a ListView?

Comment: There are much easier things than creating old web services. why dont u look at Web.API or WCF? they are very easy to use setup, configure etc.

Comment: I'm limited with the production infrastructure which is not very recent.

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to create simple web service on google very easily.

I want to show you how to get data from .net web service:

first, you have to use ksoap2 library for getting data in android.

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/ download and copy into project>libs folder

second, you have to use asynctask for calling web service because you have to use asynctask for long time process in android.

If you download and copy ksoap2 library into project, lets get started.

```
//import ksoap2

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


public class Example extends Activity {

    //define your web service namespace
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";  
    //web service URL
private static final String URL = "http://www.example.com/webservice1.asmx";


//variables
private String username;
private String password;
private String userID;


public class ExampleAS extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Example.this);       
    String ParamUserName;
    String ParamPassword;

    public ExampleAS(String ParamUserName,String ParamPassword){
        this.ParamUserName=ParamUserName;
        this.ParamPassword=ParamPassword;

    }

    @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.show();
     }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ExampleFunc(ParamUserName,ParamPassword);
        return userID;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String userID){
        label.setText(userID);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}

private String ExampleFunc(String ParamUserName,String ParamPassword){
    PropertyInfo uName = new PropertyInfo();
    uName.name= "USERNAME"; //It must be same with your webservice's parameter name
    uName.setValue(ParamUserName); //Parameter value
    uName.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS; //Parameter type

    PropertyInfo pass = new PropertyInfo();
    pass.name= "PASSWORD"; //It must be same with your webservice's parameter name      
            pass.setValue(ParamPassword); //Parameter value
    pass.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS; //Parameter type

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Login"); //Namespace,Webservice method name
    request.addProperty(uName);
    request.addProperty(pass);


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.bodyOut=request;
    envelope.dotNet = true; 
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    try {

        androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/Login", envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        Object property = response.getProperty(0);
        if(property instanceof SoapObject){
            SoapObject users = (SoapObject) property;
                userID = users.getProperty("user_id").toString();
                }

 } 
         catch (Exception e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    return userID;

}
```

Don't copy and build it, It may not working because I write it on here. You should change some field for your request or getting data from web service.

You must call asynctask in onCreate

forexample;

```
new ExampleAS("admin","1234").execute();
```

finally, you should follow my another post :[Get List from .net Web Service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734702/get-list-from-net-web-service-on-android)